# What should I do when an issue is solved but brings me a new issue in the same context?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Trying to *install from source* a program I get an error in the `./configure` command.

I created a question ([here](https://askubuntu.com/q/267565/62483)) with this error and it was correctly answered and this error is now gone. But after that, in the same command, I get new/different errors.

So, what should I do in such a case?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Create a new question

The first question was solved and the user who created the answer should be recognized by the effort made (reputation awarded).

The new errors should be solved separately, by creating a new question, linked to the original (for the sake of context).

---

*Answer emerged from the [conversation](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8515898#8515898) with @Jorge*

Comment: What this guy said. Just create a new question, mentioning the last question as background.

Comment: When you do create the new question, write/copy all relevant context into the new question, too.  Don't just link to the other question and say "I did what was said in my previous question (link), but it's giving me this error".  It's better if people don't have to follow links to other questions in order to figure out what you're asking.